# Xcode 6 Bug for Swift Functions?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm a newbie in iOS development. Here is a weird error I receive when I try to use functions written in Swift
Can you suggest what I should try to do?
This might be a bug in Xcode 6.

[image]

Comment: It's not weird, you are not using functions correctly

Comment: I think you are not very much experienced on programming, and it would be better to focus on one language if you're really new to programming. And if you want to learn Swift, I recommend you to wait until it to be formally released at this fall. The language is under development, then it will **change** a lot until it to be released. That will make you suffer.

Comment: you cannot put a method call in the _class's scope_... put those lines into a _function's scope_ instead.

Comment: Thank you guys, I got it. Please don't answer anymore or rate it down :)

Comment: I don't think this question should have been down voted. It's naive but that doesn't make it a bad question. It's focused to a single issue and provides enough information for a clear cut answer.  Lots of naive newbie programmers out there might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a bug in your code.  You can't invoke functions inside a `class` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing class code with playgrounds code. In a class, you can only invoke methods from within other methods, try moving `heyy()` and the `println` line inside the viewDidLoad method and all should be fine

Answer (score 0):

A class is more like a schematic document rather then a program code flow. Then, you cannot put a command statements (such as calling function) in a class scope. (between `{}`)